# Add Objects in the right context to "pscustomobject"-Output [Powershell]

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

The following script generates a report with the following output objects "Role", "ResourceRole ObjectID" and "Target ObjectID"

```
#Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.ReadWrite.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All", "EntitlementManagement.ReadWrite.All"
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Identity.Governance

# Read resource roles, split into individual strings
$ResourceRoles = Get-MgBetaEntitlementManagementAccessPackageAssignmentResourceRole <#-- -all --#> | Select-Object OriginId, OriginSystem, Status
$ResourceRoles_trim = $ResourceRoles.OriginId -split ',\s*' | ForEach-Object Trim
# Create 3 seperate objects
$OutputFile = $ResourceRoles_trim | ForEach-Object {
  # start by splitting the string into 3 after `_`
 $Type,$ResourceRole,$Target = $_ -split '_'
  # create the object
  [pscustomobject]@{
    "Role" = $Type
    "ResourceRole Objectid" = $ResourceRole
    "Target Objectid" = $Target
  }
}
# Export to CSV
$OutputFile | Export-Csv 'C:\ResourceRoles.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
Role       ResourceRole Objectid                Target Objectid
----       ---------------------                ---------------
Member     b4t0fb7b-13fd-4hd2-9663-3a4dd38cg636 3a55dd46-6eed-78dd-7d35-c9derdce5f4c
Member     ad9t7vfc-fv5t-466d-f36d-4671dc066ed7 3a55dd46-6eed-78dd-7d35-c9derdce5f4c
```

My Question is: How to add additional Objects

```
OriginSystem, Status
```

...from the

```
$ResourceRoles = Get-MgBetaEntitlementManagementAccessPackageAssignmentResourceRole <#-- -all --#> | Select-Object OriginId, OriginSystem, Status
```

request, with the correct connection to ID?

Regards

i have no clue how to add

```
OriginSystem, Status
```

...to

```
pscustomobject
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `$ResourceRoles_trim`?

Comment: It's possible that joining objects will combine themin the way you want.  Search on Join-Object.  That's a function that some brave soul has added to the basic repertoire in powershell.

Comment: @sirtao 

Output: '$ResourceRoles_trim
Member_b4t0fb7b-13fd-4hd2-9663-3a4dd38cg636_3a55dd46-6eed-78dd-7d35-c9derdce5f4c'

it just split the main object for seperate the Member/User/Group, finaly to merge against the Displayname

Comment: @WalterMitty thank you for feedback, "jon" is a good hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER:

```
#Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'User.ReadWrite.All', 'Group.ReadWrite.All', 'EntitlementManagement.ReadWrite.All'
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Identity.Governance

# Read resource roles, limits it to 3 properties for collection index
$ResourceRoles = Get-MgBetaEntitlementManagementAccessPackageAssignmentResourceRole <#-- -all --#> | Select-Object OriginId, OriginSystem, Status


$OutputFile = $ResourceRoles | ForEach-Object {

    # start by splitting the string into 3 after `_`
    $Type, $ResourceRole, $Target = $_.OriginId -split '_'

    # create the object
    [pscustomobject]@{
        'OriginSystem'          = $_.OriginSystem
        'Status'                = $_.Status
        'Role'                  = $Type
        'ResourceRole Objectid' = $ResourceRole
        'Target Objectid'       = $Target
    }
}

# Export to CSV
$OutputFile | Export-Csv 'C:\ResourceRoles.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

OLD ANSWER:

this should be enough, I think:

```
[pscustomobject]@{
    "OriginSystem"          = $ResourceRoles.OriginSystem
    "Status"                = $ResourceRoles.status
    "Role"                  = $Type
    "ResourceRole Objectid" = $ResourceRole
    "Target Objectid"       = $Target
}
```

Comment: Note that the `$ResourceRoles_trim` value is determined via [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), i.e. it is based on the `.OriginId` values _across all elements of `$ResourceRoles`_, so your solution would only work if `$ResourceRoles` happened to contain just _one_ object, but the `Get-MgBetaEntitlementManagementAccessPackageAssignmentResourceRole <#-- -all --#>` part suggests that _multiple_ ones are expected.

Comment: Reasonable but `-All` is commented out, so I am guessing there will be only one element.     

More in general, without knowing what exactly the function returns(I haven't been able to find information on the nature of `[Microsoft.Graph.Beta.PowerShell.Models.IMicrosoftGraphAccessPackageAssignmentResourceRole]`), it looks to me it returns an object with a single `.OriginId` string property.

Comment: Good point about the `-All` being commented out - I had assumed the comment to indicates that `-All` is _implied_, but I don't know and consulting the exceptionally poor [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.beta.identity.governance/get-mgbetaentitlementmanagementaccesspackageassignmentresourcerole?view=graph-powershell-beta) doesn't shed light on this.

Comment: yeah, the "Related" section links to itself... very useful documentation

Comment: @sirtao
i already try this way, unfortunately this output happen:
' OriginSystem          : {AadGroup, AadGroup, AadGroup, AadGroup…}
Status                : {Fulfilled, Fulfilled, Fulfilled, Fulfilled…}'

I dont know how to avoid loops?

Regards

Comment: About '-All': without i get up tp 100 entries, when using '-All', i get all Data, more than 1K entries.

Comment: I _THINK_ I have a solution but @vipfafen could you update your question with the first couple of lines from the `C:\ResourceRolesBefore.csv` file you are currently getting with your script?       

The main issue here is that we do not know the structure of the data and that might help

Comment: @sirtao, "C:\ResourceRolesBefore.csv" isn't necessary, i just comment out this part.

Output of `$Output`:

```
OriginSystem : {AadGroup, AadGroup, AadGroup, AadGroup…}
Status       : {Fulfilled, Fulfilled, Fulfilled, Fulfilled…}
Role         : Member
UserID       : 363e2916-3d40-4951-b363-47049f730444
GroupID      : 68dc228b-b101-46b2-8275-921e6f6j5a5t
```

So there is a loop or something else

Comment: I did ask for the content of that CSV because it should have some of the structure of  `$ResourceRoles` in a human-readable form; I guess I could have asked you that.

Comment: Output of `C:\ResourceRolesBefore.csv`

Output:
`OriginId OriginSystem Status

`Member_b4t0fb7b-13fd-4hd2-9663-3a4dd38cg636_3a55dd46-6eed-78dd-7d35-c9derdce5f4c AadGroup Fulfilled`

Comment: @vipfafen updated the answer, check it out if you want